# DefaultTextForegroundThemeBrush overrides TextBox style

Tags: c#, xaml, styling, winui-3, winui

## Problem

Hey guys,
I've got a problem regarding the `DefaultTextForegroundThemeBrush` in WinUi 3. I read [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.textblock.foreground?view=winrt-22621) that I can use the `DefaultTextForegroundThemeBrush` to override the foreground value for all default text.

However if I override that Brush with my desired color (white) most of the `TextBlock`s get white (not all though and I do not know why either).
Strangely all `TextBox`es will get gray by default and the Text inside will be black. Even though I did override the `BackgroundBrush` for `TextBox`es as well.
For me it seems like a pretty strange behavior I couldn't get behind.
Furthermore only `TextBox`es are affected. A `PasswordBox` I use remains unaffected.

I did not find anything googling for this strange behavior.

Maybe some of you guys can help me. Let me know if you need anything else.

Kind regards!

## Code

### Overriding TextControl Brushes

```
<Thickness x:Key="TextControlBorderThemeThickness">1,1,1,1</Thickness>

<SolidColorBrush x:Key="TextControlBackground" Color="{ThemeResource PrussianBlueColor}"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="TextControlBackgroundPointerOver" Color="{ThemeResource VividSkyBlueColor}"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="TextControlBackgroundFocused" Color="{ThemeResource PrussianBlueColor}"/>

<SolidColorBrush x:Key="TextControlForeground" Color="{ThemeResource WhiteColor}"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="TextControlForegroundPointerOver" Color="{ThemeResource WhiteColor}"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="TextControlForegroundFocused" Color="{ThemeResource WhiteColor}"/>

<SolidColorBrush x:Key="TextControlButtonForeground" Color="{ThemeResource WhiteColor}"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="TextControlButtonForegroundPointerOver" Color="{ThemeResource WhiteColor}"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="TextControlButtonForegroundPressed" Color="{ThemeResource LighterBlackColor}"/>

<SolidColorBrush x:Key="TextControlBorderBrush" Color="{ThemeResource VividSkyBlueColor}"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="TextControlBorderBrushPointerOver" Color="{ThemeResource CarolinaBlueColor}"/>

<SolidColorBrush x:Key="TextControlPlaceholderForeground" Color="{ThemeResource LighterBlackColor}"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="TextControlPlaceholderForegroundFocused" Color="{ThemeResource LighterBlackColor}"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="TextControlPlaceholderForegroundPointerOver" Color="{ThemeResource LighterBlackColor}"/>
```

### Overriding DefaultTextForegroundThemeBrush

```
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="DefaultTextForegroundThemeBrush" Color="{ThemeResource WhiteColor}"/>
```

## Screenshots

[TextBox without DefaultTextForegroundThemeBrush  set](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2SFyt.png)

[TextBox with DefaultTextForegroundThemeBrush set](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CgBwg.png)

Comment: See at the top of the [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.textblock.foreground?view=winrt-22621) you posted. You are looking at the ``TextBlock``'s ``TextProperty``. So, ``DefaultTextForegroundThemeBrush`` shouldn't change your ``TextBox`` color. At least, in my environment it didn't.

Comment: @AndrewKeepCoding That's what I was expecting too. It surprises me even more that this problem does not occur in your environment. If I activate Hot reload when the program is running and then delete all TextControl switches just to add them again the TextBoxes look normal again. It seems to be some kind of timing issue on startup or something?

Comment: Style code around your controls might help to help you.